# How can I set a variable to false when .searchable modifier is active?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this SwiftUI code, I have a view that contains a search bar and underneath the search bar are some filter tags that are in a capsule shape & an image.

When the search bar is tapped, the keyboard shifts up the view and the filter tags cover the search bar.

I want to alter the code so that showingTags is set to false when the search bar has been tapped in order to avoid this UI error

I tried using .onTapGesture{} on the .searchable modifier but this didn't seem to work. How can I make sure the tags are not shown when the search bar has been tapped?

Here is my code:

```
struct ProductSearchView: View {

    @StateObject var marketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @State var searchText = ""
    @State var product_array_status = true
    @State var product_array_status_search = false
    @State var product_array_status_tags = false
    @State var showingTags: Bool = true

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color("BG")
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {

                if showingTags {
                    TagView()
                }
               
                if product_array_status_search {
                    VStack(spacing: 15) {
                        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(marketplaceModel.filteredProduct.filter { ($0.product_name ?? "").contains(searchText)}, id: \.self) { product in

                                ProductSearchRow(productData: product)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        showingTags.toggle()
                    }
                } else if product_array_status_tags {
                    VStack(spacing: 15) {
                        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(marketplaceModel.product_tag_array, id: \.self) { product in

                                ProductSearchRow(productData: product)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Image("PlaceholderImage")
                        .resizable()

                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
 .onAppear {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            self.marketplaceModel.fetchProductData(key: keyString)
        }
        .onChange(of: marketplaceModel.search, perform: { value in
            // to avoid Continues Search requests....
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                if value == marketplaceModel.search && marketplaceModel.search != ""{
                    // Search Data....
                    marketplaceModel.filterData()
                }
            }
            if marketplaceModel.search == ""{
                // reset all data....
                withAnimation(.linear) {
                    product_array_status = true
                    product_array_status_search = false
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

How do I ensure TagView() is not displayed when the search bar provided by .searchable has been tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the environment value [`isSearching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/issearching) to detect if the search text field is focused.

You should declare an `Environment`, not in `ProductSearchView`, but in one of the subviews of the `searchable` view. Since this determines the visibility of the `TagView`, it's probably the easiest if you put it in `TagView`:

```
struct TagView: View {
    @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching: Bool
    var body: some View {
        if !isSearching {
            // put the original contents of "body" here...
        }
        // if isSearching is true, then the body is empty. The view is basically "hidden".
    }
}
```

Now you don't even need `showingTags`!