# How to open collapsed List Sections on focus of Search Bar?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-searchable

In my SwiftUI app, I have a `List` with a collapsible `Section` of row items. I'm using SwiftUI's `.searchable` on the list. When a user runs a search from the search bar, all the collapsed sections remain collapsed, even if the search returns results within that section.

How would I open all collapsed sections before a search is run? In other words, how would I expand all sections when the search bar is focused?

Here is a GIF of all the UI elements if you're unfamiliar. No actual search is being run, obviously.

[image: demo]

Here is a stripped down code example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var showingSection = true
    
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section(
                    isExpanded: $showingSection,
                    content: {
                        Text("One")
                        Text("Two")
                        Text("Three")
                    },
                    header: { Text("Section") }
                )
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried simply placing the `@Environment(\.isSearching)` variable as the value for the Section's `isExpanded` attribute (its value would be `true` when searching, so I thought it would set `isExpanded` to `true` too), but I get the error "Cannot find '$isSearching' in scope":

```swift
Section(
    isExpanded: $isSearching,
    ...
```

---

*I'm a Swift novice here and trying to not only learn the "how" but also the "why". I'd be grateful if that was a part of any answers too!*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a variable to false when .searchable modifier is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693882/how-can-i-set-a-variable-to-false-when-searchable-modifier-is-active)

Answer (score 0):

This was [answered in this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/178rzsv/comment/k54fhjx/?context=3):

> move the section to a separate file and it should work and don’t pass
> the issearching as a parameter
>
> for the isSearching to work it has to be in a childview where the
> parent has the .searchable modifier
>
> ...
>
> you'd have to still use the onChange and showingSectionOne inside the
> subview, you can't directly use isSearching as a binding.

So, the parent view would be:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                SectionView()
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}
```

And the child view would be:

```swift
struct SectionView: View {
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
    @State var sectionExpanded: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(
            isExpanded: $sectionExpanded,
            content: {
                Text("One")
                Text("Two")
                Text("Three")
            },
            header: { Text("Section") }
        )
        .onChange(of: isSearching, { oldValue, newValue in
            if (newValue == true && oldValue == false) {
                sectionExpanded = true
            }
        })
    }
}
```